# three.js object intersection

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I was trying to make some surface with cubes intersect it, and thats what I am getting. I dont know if it should be like that on the current stage of Three,js development.

[image: object intersection issue]

In the [dragable cubes example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html) everything is ok. I thought that maybe I am using wrong materials or renderer.

```
var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors });
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CanvasRenderer` [does not use a z-buffer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/43). You should switch to a `WebGLRenderer` to fix the problem.

Comment: Or add more subdivisions to the cube... `new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 2, 2, 2 )`